# How to fetch an endpoint in another endpoint?

Tags: sveltekit

I have an endpoint in `/api/metadata`, and I want to fetch it in another endpoint like this:

```js
export const get: RequestHandler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(event.url + '/api/metadata')

        const body = await res.json()

        return {
            body
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return {
            status: 500
        };
    }
};
```

But I got the following error:

```
FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/sitemap.xml/api/metadata failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
```

When I change the fetch location to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/metadata` the fetch would just work. Is it possible for me to handle this fetch request correctly without using conditional with `process.env.NODE_ENV`(the `dev` in `$app/env`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`event.url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) contains full URL (with pathname, query string, etc.).

Try to use [`event.url.origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/origin):

```
const res = await fetch(event.url.origin + '/api/metadata')
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be better to wrap the main logic of the `/api/metadata` endpoint into its own module, then import that module in both endpoints. So your code would look like this (in both endpoints):

```
import { getMetadata } from '$lib/metadata.js'


export const get: RequestHandler = async (event) => {
    try {
        // const res = await fetch(event.url + '/api/metadata')

        // const body = await res.json()

        const body = getMetadata();


        return {
            body
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return {
            status: 500
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Would it also be ok to run 'getmetadata()' at 'metadata.js' and then just export and import the json object, rather than running the function multiple times? or is there a reason why that would be a bad idea?

Comment: There is nothing in the question that indicates the metadata doesn't change. If the metadata can change, you want to call the function every time. If the metadata doesn't change, you might as well just export the JSON object directly, without calling `getmetadata()` at all. @treeseal7